# Textbox on canvas drag direction changed after rotated

Tags: c#, canvas, rotation, windows-phone, transform

I have a textblock control on canvas which can be dragged horizontally to the right correctly as shown in the first and second image.

Then after I a 90 degree rotation angle is applied to its CompositeTransform, dragging the textblock to the right actually move it vertically towards the top as shown by the third and fourth image. What am I missing?

```
public CompositeTransform CurrentTransform = new CompositeTransform();
..... 
TextBlock.RenderTransform = CurrentTransform;

....
    private double angle;
    public double Angle 
    { 
        get
        {
            return angle;
        }
        set
        {
            if (angle != value)
            {
                angle = value;     
                CurrentTransform.CenterX = 0;
                CurrentTransform.CenterY = 0;            
                CurrentTransform.Rotation = angle;                                          
            }
        }
    }
```

The moving of the textbox is handled inside

```
private void CanvasText_ManipulationDelta(object sender, System.Windows.Input.ManipulationDeltaEventArgs e)
    {
          CurrentTransform.TranslateX += e.DeltaManipulation.Translation.X;
          CurrentTransform.TranslateY += e.DeltaManipulation.Translation.Y;
    }
```

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

For those who are in the same boat, I managed to fix this by attaching external gesture listener from Windows Phone toolkit instead of using the built-in `CanvasText_ManipulationDelta` event. The textbox dragging works correctly even after rotation.

```
        <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
            <Image x:Name="ImageOriginal" 
                   Source="{Binding WbPreview, Mode=TwoWay}"
                   Stretch="Uniform"/>                
            <Grid x:Name="GridDraw" 
                  Tap="GridDraw_Tap"
                  Background="Transparent"/>
            <Canvas x:Name="CanvasText">
                <toolkit:GestureService.GestureListener>
                    <toolkit:GestureListener Tap="GestureListener_Tap"
                    DragDelta="GestureListener_DragDelta"/>
                </toolkit:GestureService.GestureListener>
            </Canvas> 

        </Grid>
```